# How should anything more complex than small libraries be presented in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I am a bit baffled by the structure. For instance, say I want to document an entire class as part of a framework. If I choose to create a topic for that class, I am left with a *Syntax* section that is too broad to contain the internal mechanics of the entire class and an *Examples* section that at least allows for some structural partitioning (that is, methods can be separated from one another) but is semantically misleading.

Now what happens if I want to create a topic on a module that contains a number of classes? Trying to keep all topics nested to the same depth becomes awkward very fast.

Is there any plan to rectify this in the future? How are we supposed to handle organizational issues as such?